# Incorrect Hash MD5 In SOAP Service

Tags: php, web-services, soap, yii, hash

I am having my soap service in yii. I want to send a file content and file content hash to soap service where I need to check if content_hash sent and content_hash generated from content is the same or not. I am using hash function as MD5. My issue is that hash content doesn't match always.

nusoap client code:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Pacific/Auckland');
// Pull in the NuSOAP code
require_once('./nusoap/lib/nusoap.php');
// Create the client instance
$client = new nusoap_client('http://localhost/my-project/web/handler', true);
$err = $client->getError();
if ($err) {
    // Display the error
    echo '<h2>Constructor error</h2><pre>' . $err . '</pre>';
    // At this point, you know the call that follows will fail
}
$proxy = $client->getProxy();

$content = file_get_contents('C:/TEST.txt');
$content_hash = md5($content);

$result = $proxy->getUpload("$content_hash", "$content");
print_r($result);
?>
```

Yii soap function:

```
     /**
     * @param string $content_hash
     * @param string $content
     * @return string
     * @soap
     */

    public function getUpload($content_hash,$content){
        return $content_hash.'-----------'.md5($content);         
    }
```

Function is working but both the hash values are different. Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that soap service removes Carriage Return what makes it a different string at server end and as the string was different hash was different. I added following to resolve it:

```
$content = str_replace("\n", "\r\n", $content);
```

It is working when I directly put all the content in a variable.